# Highlight values that are present in a range in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm making a Google Sheets that has a few pages, to keep track of turn-based game data. Right now, I have a sheet called `Current` which has a range (B5:J25) of values (all text). I have a second sheet (`TurnActions`) that has another range (B5:J25, again) of values.

Say the first sheet contains the values `Finite`, `Alexander`, and `Trackpad` in various locations, and the second contains `Hamster`, `Finite`, and `Flow`. I want `Finite` to be highlighted.

How would I use conditional formatting rules to add a red background to any values in the second sheet that are present in the first sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Please try clearing formatting from and selecting `TurnActions!B5:J25` and Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... **Custom formula is** and:

```
=countif(importrange(" k e y ","Current!B$5:$J$25"),B5)>0
```

Then select red fill and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

A conditional format rule cannot reference a different sheet directly but we 'cheat' and use [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340) to fetch what we need. Hence permission must be granted, to access the other sheet.

`k e y` is whatever is appropriate for your sheet `Current`.

Use delimiters appropriate for your locale.

[COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)